# Resoner not working with FUSEKI / OWLIM When uploading Ontology with OWL2 Property Chain

Tags: jena, owl, protege, fuseki, owlim

I wanted to make use of Property Chain in OWL and get the inference working in FUSEKI / OWLIM but I not able to get the inference working using the OWL2 property chain.

I used the Protege tool to define the Ontology. The Ontology file contains following Property Chain for "hasGrandParent" Object property

- hasParent • hasParent → hasGrandParent

When enabling the reasoner in Protege the Inference works fine and shows the relationship (hasGrandParent relationship), but when loading the same ontology file to FUSEKI / OWLIM the inference doesn't work. I am sure missing something with the configuration.

Can anyone please help in getting this working.

Comment: The Jena reasoners only support the first version of OWL (and not quite all of it, at that).  Property chains were introduced in OWL2, so the built in Jena reasoners don't handle them.  It might not be too hard to extend the Jena reasoners with support for property chains, though.

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB (OWLIM) supports this since version 4. The `owl:propertyChainAxiom` rule https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#prp-spo2 is implemented thus:

```
Id: prp_spo2_1
    p <owl:propertyChainAxiom> pc
    start pc last                   [Context <onto:_checkChain>]
    ----------------------------
    start p last

Id: prp_spo2_2
    pc <rdf:first> p
    pc <rdf:rest> t                 [Constraint t != <rdf:nil>]
    start p next
    next t last                     [Context <onto:_checkChain>]
    ----------------------------
    start pc last                   [Context <onto:_checkChain>]

Id: prp_spo2_3
    pc <rdf:first> p
    pc <rdf:rest> <rdf:nil>
    start p last
    ----------------------------
    start pc last                   [Context <onto:_checkChain>]
```

However, you can implement a similar functionality faster if you limit yourself to chains of length 2. See here: http://vladimiralexiev.github.io/pres/extending-owl2/